# Trouble Viewing HTML Website in Firefox and mobile devices

Tags: html

Recently I have created my own html website for first time by learning from http://www.w3schools.com/ and http://www.tizag.com/htmlT/, however I am having trouble viewing my webpages in firefox and mobile devices. I really do not know where I am going wrong. Please suggest me how should I post my queries here, do I need to print my html texts here ? I am afraid it will be long total of 8 pages.

Many thanks in advance.

Riz

This is my Banner.html code and in Firefox, marquee creates malfunctioning, I guess there is lot of mistakes in my code, please advice me accordingly, thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
body {
background-color: #696969;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
} 
#banner {
width: 75%;
height: 170px;
display: block;
float: right; 
}
h1 {
position: absolute;
color: #ffffff;
left: 20px;
top: 0px;
 letter-spacing: 5px;
 font-size: 50px;
float:left;
}
h3 {
position: absolute;
color: #ffffff;
text-shadow: 0 0 10px #ffd700;
left: 20px;
top: 78px;
letter-spacing: 2.4px;  
float: left;
}
span {color: #ffd700;}
span.g {color:#ffffff; text-shadow: 0 0 10px #ffd700;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<marquee loop="true" direction="up" scrollamount="2"><img id="banner"  src="handshake1.jpg" alt="BannerImage"><img id="banner" src="web.jpg" alt="BannerImage"><img id="banner" src="art.jpg" alt="BannerImage"><img id="banner" src="flower.jpg" alt="BannerImage" style="height:230px"><img id="banner" src="apple.jpg" alt="BannerImage" style="height:230px"><img id="banner" src="green.jpg" alt="Banner Image"><img id="banner" src="ocean.jpg" alt="BannerImage" style="height:250px"></marquee>
<h1><span>Stack</span><span class="g">Overflow</span></h1>
<h3>Online&nbsp;&#38;&nbsp;Communications</h3>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i think putting some code from one page it might be enough for other to help you

Answer (score 1):

A typical mobile-optimized site contains something like the following:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

For pages that set an initial or maximum scale, this means the width property actually translates into a minimum viewport width. For example, if your layout needs at least 500 pixels of width then you can use the following markup. When the screen is more than 500 pixels wide, the browser will expand the viewport (rather than zoom in) to fit the screen:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=500, initial-scale=1">


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<title>Stack Overflow Forums</title>
    <meta name="google-site-verification"  content="y4IbEwKh_krYR4qU0TDeK_R28IJCVCApOIuAm1w1n9c">
    <meta name="viewport" content ="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,user-scalable=yes">
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1"> 
    <meta content="Learning HTML, Website Tutorials" name="Keywords">
    <meta content="Website Tutorials" name="keywords">
    <meta content="HTML Training, etc.." name="description">
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1800">
</head>
<frameset rows="30%,70%">
<frame name="banner" src="banner.html" noresize scrolling="no">
<frame name="home" src="home.html">
</frameset>
</html>
```

Comment: Jon, please have a look at my index.html, once my mistakes has been sorted out, I will insert the above tag, thanks.

Comment: Hi, you should consider running your code through a validator such as http://validator.w3.org/ it will help you correct your code. I placed an edit in my answer for you to look at.

Comment: Thanks Jon, I am seriously considering removing frames completely as per you and Lee advised. I have tested it and found it cool, Now i have edited my question and pasted the banner.html codes, please advise me accordingly.

Comment: @JonSnow Your Viewport meta tag isn't in the right place if you're demonstrating your code as full and working, it should be within the `<head>` and `</head>` tags.

Comment: Yes, I had assumed that as well, according to w3 validator it was thrown it up as an error which is why it ended up outside of the head tag.

Comment: Hello Jon, I came across another problem with the Firefox related to fonts, I have posted my question with another tag already, but still no solutions, shall I continue here with that question or guide me regards to this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should be marking up your page properly, using `body` tags and getting away from framesets.

You'll get a much better output across mobile browsers and other browsers if it's all kept to strict HTML standards.

For example, a basic HTML page layout:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Stackoverflow Forums</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="banner">
        // Your banner HTML
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        // Your main content HTML
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

You can still use all of the things you had inside your head tag, but these will create `divs` that can be seen as 'blocks' that help separate sections of code.

This page is quite good to take a read through - http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_intro.asp

Comment: what will be alternative HTML format other than framesets, I am damn new to Websites, I prefer to step up one by one starting from HTML perfectly, let me add the body tag and see, thanks.

Comment: Lee, When I have added the <body> (below <html> tag) </body> (above </html> tag), the page open with blank, however when I removed the body tags, page starts working normally.

Comment: You'll need to remove your `frame` tags, and copy and paste everything from home.html and put it into your main index file. It will need some vast editing, but it will be much better when it's done properly. The reason being, that frames are old, and are starting to be non-supported.

Comment: Thanks Lee, I have followed your advise and did the same, I found it very cool, now please look at my banner.html code and advise me accordingly.

Comment: Hmm well the marquee I would suggest you get rid of, and take a look at some JS alternatives. The marquee tag has now been deprecated and is no longer supported. But with the code, you just need to strip out everything that isn't inside the `<body>` and `</body>` tags, and copy and paste it into your main file